# How to find Wordpress Login page. /wp-admin | /wp-login etc does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day, hope you are well.

I have taken over a project for a client that had another developer do custom work. I have been tasked to just make a few design changes.

My problem is not being able to access the login page to the dashboard.

I have tried using:

```
http://domainname.com/wp-admin
http://domainname.com/wp-login
http://domainname.com/wp-admin.php
http://domainname.com/wp-login.php
http://domainname.com/admin
http://domainname.com/login
```

And none of them work.

I have also checked the `wp-admin.php` and `wp-login.php` files with no success.

For this reason I am unable to access the dashboard.

Comment: You share really few infomrations to help, but maybe the site is done with https://roots.io/bedrock/. In this case the URL is `http://www.domain.ext/wp/wp-admin`

Comment: Or the site use some security plugin, who change `/wp-admin` to anything you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because some security plugin is involved. Can you access the site via FTP? If so, navigate to the `/wp-content/plugins/` and disable security plugin by moving out the plugin folder. **Make backup** of the plugin folder before!

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I managed to pin it down to a plugin called iThemes Security Plugin. Have a great day and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, try to add index.php after the domain name in case there are redirect problems on your server or if the domain name is not correctly configured.
As :
http://domainname.com/index.php/wp-admin